# How can I remove dragon priest masks from a follower's inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was moving my house in Skyrim had my follower (Vilkas) pick up my things so I could fast travel.

At the new house I attempted to take them back, but it refused to allow me to take any of the dragon priest masks from his inventory. I was forced to kill him to reclaim them. Is there another way to get the masks back that doesnt result in his death? Is this a problem for all followers?

I play on a console, so system commands are not helpful.

Comment: Load an earlier save and don't give them to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell him to wait there then go to 10 other towns, come back and voilà, he will give them to you.

Comment: Why did you reject my edit? This has nothing to do with voila, its vilkas!

Comment: @Jim don't threaten people. I rejected it.

Comment: @Jim Voila is a french word that means something like "done". No need to edit. Also he isn't rejecting it, [people over 2k do](http://ardao.me/files/512.png).

Comment: @Jim As a side note, if your edit gets rejected, suggesting it again doesn't really work very well. Especially when you then threaten said rejecters with retaliation. Don't do that. Understand what is being asked, don't assume you are automatically correct. You're not.

Comment: @Frank All right. It's just that I don't really understand about these answers that I try to edit them.

Comment: @ardaozkal it's just that I don't know much about French I thought he mentioned that lady who hunts for the murderer in Windhelm.

Comment: @Jim voilà is known worldwide, but you might not know it, it is normal as not all languages are influenced by french. Please ask over at Chat for more info about why your edit might be rejected in the future.

Comment: There are no characters named **voilà**.  You thought of **Viola**.  Close, but not the same.  You should Google words you do not understand.  There is no excuse in this day and age.  The answer also has an accent on the a, and that is a very deliberate thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try sending him home and pickpocketing him while he's walking away.

Answer (score 0):

Try pick pocketing him, or talk to him and say "I need to trade something with you" and replace the mask with another helmet.